# UIImagePicker to NSData with GPS metadata without saving to photo album

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

I've managed to add GPS coordinate to the metadata by following these steps :

1. Retrieve UIIMage from UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera
2. Saving to disk (`writeImageToSavedPhotosAlbum`) with geolocalized metadata
3. Read from disk with `ALAsset` and convert it to jpeg `NSData`

Can I do the same without the hassle of a saving/reading to disk?

Comment: how do you do step 2? Are you acquiring the location yourself or getting it from IOImagePickerController? Please explain.

Comment: I've added an answer for this.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with some difficulty using Quartz. You can get the CGImage from the UIImage, combine it with metadata to create a new CGImage. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2872341/1633251) for one such discussion, but by searching with the Quartz names and the term "metadata" should result in others.

Answer (score 1):

In the `UIImagePickerControllerDelegate`:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    [Utils ifLocationEnabledDo:^{
        switch (picker.sourceType) {
            case UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera:
            {   
                UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
                NSMutableDictionary *metadata = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithDictionary:[info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerMediaMetadata]];
                [Utils setLocation:metadata location:[SharedAppDelegate getCurrentLocation]];
                [[Utils getAssetsLibrary] writeImageDataToSavedPhotosAlbum:image metadata:metadata completionBlock:nil];
            }
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }];
}
```

And in my `Utils` class:

```
+ (void)setLocation:(NSMutableDictionary *)metadata location:(CLLocation *)location
{

    if (location) {

        CLLocationDegrees exifLatitude  = location.coordinate.latitude;
        CLLocationDegrees exifLongitude = location.coordinate.longitude;

        NSString *latRef;
        NSString *lngRef;
        if (exifLatitude < 0.0) {
            exifLatitude = exifLatitude * -1.0f;
            latRef = @"S";
        } else {
            latRef = @"N";
        }

        if (exifLongitude < 0.0) {
            exifLongitude = exifLongitude * -1.0f;
            lngRef = @"W";
        } else {
            lngRef = @"E";
        }

        NSMutableDictionary *locDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        if ([metadata objectForKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyGPSDictionary]) {
            [locDict addEntriesFromDictionary:[metadata objectForKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyGPSDictionary]];
        }
        [locDict setObject:[self getUTCFormattedDate:location.timestamp] forKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyGPSTimeStamp];
        [locDict setObject:latRef forKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyGPSLatitudeRef];
        [locDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:exifLatitude] forKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyGPSLatitude];
        [locDict setObject:lngRef forKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyGPSLongitudeRef];
        [locDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:exifLongitude] forKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyGPSLongitude];
        [locDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:location.horizontalAccuracy] forKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyGPSDOP];
        [locDict setObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:location.altitude] forKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyGPSAltitude];

        [metadata setObject:locDict forKey:(NSString*)kCGImagePropertyGPSDictionary];
    }
}
```