# Writing image metadata (EXIF/TIFF/IPTC) to image file in OS X

Tags: objective-c, macos, exif, nsimage, iptc

I am creating a photo editing app, and so far I've managed to read the metadata from image files successfully (after getting an answer to this question: [Reading Camera data from EXIF while opening NSImage on OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19665593/reading-camera-data-from-exif-while-opening-nsimage-on-os-x)).

```
source = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)url, NULL);
NSDictionary *props = (__bridge_transfer NSDictionary *) CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(source, 0, NULL);
```

This copies all the metadata of the image file to a dictionary, and it works faily well. However, I couldn't find out how to write this metadata back to a newly created `NSImage` (or to an image file). Here is how I save my file (where `img` is an NSImage instance *without* metadata and `self.cachedMetadata` is the dictionary read from the initial image):

```
NSBitmapImageRep *rep = [NSBitmapImageRep imageRepWithData:[img TIFFRepresentation]];
[rep setProperty:NSImageEXIFData withValue:self.cachedMetadata];
NSData *data;
if([[fileName lowercaseString] rangeOfString:@".png"].location != NSNotFound){
    data = [rep representationUsingType:NSPNGFileType properties:nil];
}else if([[fileName lowercaseString] rangeOfString:@".tif"].location != NSNotFound){
    data = [rep representationUsingType:NSTIFFFileType properties:nil];
}else{ //assume jpeg
    data = [rep representationUsingType:NSJPEGFileType properties:@{NSImageCompressionFactor: [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1], NSImageEXIFData: self.cachedMetadata}];
}

[data writeToFile:fileName atomically:YES];
```

How can I write the metadata? I used to write just EXIF for JPEG (the dictionary was EXIF-only previously) successfully but because EXIF lacked some of the fields that the initial images had (IPTC and TIFF tags) I needed to change my reading method. Now I have all the data, but I don't know how to write it to the newly-created image file.

Thanks,
Can.

Comment: hello! I am more or less in the same situation but cannot understand your solution. I have alist of keywords, titile and description i must write to the IPTC section of a jpg i know the path of. how can this be done? could you please have a look at this question and maybe post an answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23874865/write-iptc-data-to-file

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Found an answer from another StackOverflow question: [How do you overwrite image metadata?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19033974/how-do-you-overwrite-image-metadata):

(code taken from that question itself and modified for my needs, which contains the answer to my question)

```
//assuming I've already loaded the image source and read the meta
CGImageSourceRef source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((__bridge CFDataRef) data, NULL);
CFStringRef imageType = CGImageSourceGetType(source);

//new empty data to write the final image data to
NSMutableData *resultData = [NSMutableData data];
CGImageDestinationRef imgDest = CGImageDestinationCreateWithData((__bridge CFMutableDataRef)(resultData), imageType, 1, NULL);

//copy image data
CGImageDestinationAddImageFromSource(imgDest, source, 0, (__bridge CFDictionaryRef)(window.cachedMetadata));
BOOL success = CGImageDestinationFinalize(imgDest);
```

This worked perfectly for writing back all the metadata including EXIF, TIFF, and IPTC.

Comment: does this also preserve the clipping path if present?

Comment: I opened a new question for this here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32160528/read-non-standard-properties-from-an-image-in-objective-c will add Bounty later tonight. Might be interesting also for you if you have asoftware for photo editing yourself.

Comment: In the link I posted there is also a sample JPG with the clipping path.. could you please have a look at it? i will give another Bounty to whoever solves it. can not open the Bounty just yet because if the answer doesnt come within 7 days its gone.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try either using, or looking at the code in, the "[exiv2](http://www.exiv2.org)" tool maybe.

Comment: I have a commercial project and the commercial license requires contacting the creator. I'd better stick with the built-in solutions. There is a way to extract all that data completely, there also must be a way to write back all that data into the image.