# Read non-standard properties from an image in objective C

Tags: objective-c, image-processing, properties, jpeg

I'm using this code ([Writing image metadata (EXIF/TIFF/IPTC) to image file in OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19692455/writing-image-metadata-exif-tiff-iptc-to-image-file-in-os-x))  to read EXIF/TIFF/IPTC data from image files. It's working great, but I would also need to copy the clipping path over. It's saved to a non standard index called "Photoshop" (just like the Others are called Iptc and similar).

I can't figure out how to access this information to copy it over to a newly created NSImage. The method in the link does not seem to access any non-standard informations. Any help appreciated. Thanks

EDIT ----

Here is a sample image: http://www.mad-sharky.com/clipping_path.jpg

This one contains a clipping path, it can be verified usign this tool: http://regex.info/exif.cgi 
you can see the "Photoshop" section. That part contains all the data I am missing with the code I am using. (Code is the same as the link above)

Comment: can you supply an image example.   ( and your code) and also are you actually seeing the property when you NSLOG

Comment: Done.. also added a Bounty!

Comment: I notice that that site uses exiftool ( http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/ ). Which I have bundled in an app before and used NSTask to make calls to it.  I can see the Photoshop tag list listed on the exiftool site. But for the life of me cannot see them in your file using the exiftool. ??

Comment: I have made a little progress but not being massive on clipping path data, what actual Tags in that lot are you after saves me guessing. Can you add them to you answer. as I may be getting them and  not realising..

Comment: @markhunte i am not sure I am understanding what you are asking...

Comment: I get a lot of tags.  tags are the names of the data fields. i.e slice, IPTCDigest and so on, what individual ones are you after..? because I may or may not be getting them. Please specify in your question..

Comment: oh, now i get it.. I would need all of them, since I would like to have the new image as similar to the original as possible. Thanks!

Comment: any news on your end? Bounty expires in about 18 hours.. would be a pitty to throw 50 pts away.

Comment: I can get most of the info using exiftool. and could use it in a NSTask. But I am not sure how usable it is.  `exiftool -a -u -g1  clipping_path.jpg` and also you would have to add the exiftool folder to the project. I have not found a way of getting the 'unkown' info with native Objective - c

Comment: I would like to avoid using external tools if possible.. :(

Comment: yep. why I did not post again. I was not happy with it and was on and off looking for an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I only have an old .psd file which does not have a clipping path. But does have layers.

This quick bit of example code uses the Photoshop image properties.
**kCGImageProperty8BIMDictionary**

```
 NSURL *imageFileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"/users/username/foo.psd"];
    CGImageSourceRef imageSource = CGImageSourceCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)imageFileURL, NULL);

    NSDictionary *properties = (__bridge_transfer NSDictionary *)CGImageSourceCopyPropertiesAtIndex(imageSource, 0,
                                                                                                    NULL);

    NSDictionary *bim = properties[(__bridge id)kCGImageProperty8BIMDictionary];

     NSLog(@"bim %@",bim);

      CFRelease(imageSource);
```

In my Image I have some image layers:

[image]

The NSLog from the code above returns

> imageRead[11220:452087] bim {
>       LayerNames =     (
>           "Layer 0",
>           "Layer 5",
>           "Layer 6",
>           "Layer 4",
>           "Layer 3",
>           "Layer 2",
>           "Layer 1"
>       );
>       Version = 1; }

If I wanted to know all the keys I could use:

```
id allKeys = [bim allKeys];
     NSLog(@"allKeys %@",allKeys);
```

And get:

> imageRead[11531:463848] allKeys (
>       Version,
>       LayerNames )

I could then use:

```
id LayerNames = [bim objectForKey:@"LayerNames"];
 NSLog(@"LayerNames %@",LayerNames);
```

to get :

> imageRead[11563:465657] LayerNames (
>       "Layer 0",
>       "Layer 5",
>       "Layer 6",
>       "Layer 4",
>       "Layer 3",
>       "Layer 2",
>       "Layer 1" )

Or

**valueForKey:**,  **allValues**

I cannot test if a clipping path would come back unfortunately

Comment: updated the post with a jpg that contains a clipping path, and added a Bounty for the answer.

Comment: gave you the Bounty just not to throw it away.. if you happen to find a solution please post it.. :) thanks

Comment: I wiil do, hopefully i will find an easier way of getting those fields

Comment: stupid question. what my final goal is, is to take an existing image, and just edit a few keywords. As far as I understood, to do so I have to create a new NSImage and copy all the data over, and the problem is to access these non standard data. Now the question: would it be possible to copy over everything "as is", without having to read these entries singularely? so create a NSImage that is the exact copy of the one on the hard drive? all I need to do is to have a identical copy, with JUST a few keywords changed, without losing all the other data.

Comment: @sharkyenergy hi, have you found any solution for this issue?

Comment: @sharkyenergy, I did not find a way to get the info natively but looking at you previous question in these comments, that is the way I would go. Copy the image and then update the copies keywords. I assume you are coping to file so you probably do not need to create a new NSImage just use one of the APIs that will copy a file in the finder. NSFilemanager I think. And then use the Coregraphics API to change the keywords of the copy. Or use Coregraphics to copy the image via NSImage/CGImage and the save it with the new info. My assumption in all this is, copying will take along the extra data..